# Rails select top n records per group (memory leak)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have this method that using find_by_sql which is return 10 latest records of each source

```
def latest_results
    Entry.find_by_sql(["
    select x.id,x.created_at,x.updated_at,x.source_id,x.`data`,x.`uuid`,x.source_entry_id
    from
      (select t.*,
        (@num:=if(@group = `source_id`, @num +1, if(@group := `source_id`, 1, 1))) row_number
          from (
      select d.id,d.created_at,d.updated_at,d.source_id,d.`data`,d.`uuid`,d.source_entry_id
      from `streams` a
      JOIN `stream_filters` b
      on b.stream_id=a.id
      JOIN `filter_results` c
      on c.filter_id=b.id
      JOIN `entries` d
      on d.id=c.entry_id
      where a.id=?
        ) t
      order by `source_id`,created_at desc
      ) as x
      where x.row_number <= 10
      ORDER BY x.created_at DESC
    ",self.id])
  end
```

It's working properly on local environment with limited records.
I have t2.micro which has 2 Gib memory to serving the application. Now this query running out my whole memory and app get frizzing.
any suggestion how can I do it better ? I want to solve this without increasing the size of machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem once. The solution with mysql variables seems neat at the first place, though it is hard to optimize. It seems that is doing a full table scan in your case.

I would recommend to fetch the sources you want to display first. And then run a second query with multiple top 10 selects, one per source, all combined with a union.

The union top 10 select will have some repetive statements which you can easily autogenerate with ruby.

```
# pseudo code
sources = Entry.group(:source).limit(n)
sql = sources.map do |source|
   "select * from entries where source = #{source} order by created_at limit 10"
end.join("\nunion all\n")

Entry.find_by_sql(sql)
```

Comment: what is second line doing ? why you put limit (10) there? I think sources should contains all sources and by a loop bundle all top 10 entires together , that might solving the memory leaking, but I'm not sure about the performance . how fast it is ?

Comment: I`ve just put limit 10 as an example. Because if you have to many sources. probably you should also not display them all in one page. Though the problem will not be mysql, but rails for rendering. With proper indexes for the date and soure type mysql should be able to process millions of records within seconds and without blowing up memory

Comment: If you really need to render a all the sources, which resulst in a lot of records i would also consider using a raw sql query with ` ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`. It will not create active record object per each entry, which will save ton of memory. We had a similar case where some report query would take 5s but the rendereing of more than 100k records woudl take minutes. Better strategy is some pagination or chunk loading anyway.

Comment: It's an API endpoint. the answer will be in json so I don't think the problem is on rendering, I'm using react to render the data.